# How do I pass value to and from sql database using flask and html

Tags: python, mysql, flask

python code for model of Event:

```
class Event(db.Model): #model structure of Event database
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_name = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    attempts = db.Column(db.String(150))
```

HTML code for registering event:

```
<h3 align="center">Register Event</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="event_name">Event Name </label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="event_name"
        name="event_name"
        placeholder="Enter event name"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Attempts">Attempts</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id="attempts"
        name="attempts"
        placeholder="Enter number of attempts allowed for this event"
      />
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

python for route on register event:

```
@auth.route('/registerEvent', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_event():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        event_name = request.form.get('event_name')
        event_name = event_name.strip()
        event_name = event_name.capitalize()
        attempts = request.form.get('attempts')
        
        """check = Event.query.filter_by(event_name=event_name).first()
        if check:
            flash('Event already exists.', category='error')"""
        if len(event_name) < 4:
            flash('Event name must be greater than 3 characters.', category='error')
        elif int(attempts) < 1:
            flash('Attempts allowed must be atleast 1', category='error')
        elif int(attempts) > 3:
            flash("Attempts allowed can't be more than 3", category='error')
        else:
            new_event = Event(event_name=event_name, attempts=attempts) 
            db.session.add(new_event)
            db.session.commit() #
            flash('Event registered with name '+event_name+' and '+attempts
                  +' number of attempts', category="sucess")
            return redirect(url_for('views.events'))
        
    return render_template("registerEvent.html", user=current_user)
```

python code for view events page:

```
@views.route("/events")
def events():
    events = Event.query.all() #Query all information in table Event into tuple events
    return render_template("events.html", events=events) #return tuple events to view
```

HTML code to view event:

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="content">
      {% for event in events %}
          <div class="event">
              <p><b>#{{ events.id }}</b></p>
              <b>
                {% if events.event_name %}
                <p><i>{{ events.event_name }}</i></p>
            {% else %}
                <p><i>No event name found in events.event_name</i></p>
            {% endif %}
              </b>
              {% if events.attempts %}
                  <p><i>{{ events.attempts }}</i></p>
              {% else %}
                  <p><i>No attempts found in events.attempts</i></p>
              {% endif %}
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my very first project so I find similar problems here already but can't really parse what I find with my project seeing this is my first project with flask/sql and I am quite the novice. Thanks for all help on the matter!

I get a line for every element I register so something gets injected. But I don't know if my error is in the injection process or the query process since I only get my errors on display saying 'No event name found in events.event_name' and 'No attempts found in events.attempts' on the webpage.